# How to display post created time according to users country like Twitter in Django?

Tags: python, django

I tried django-tz-detect but it's not working in production. I also tried django-easy-timezones module that's also not working for me.

I just want to convert UTC timezone to users country's timezone like Twitter or other social media in Django.

Comment: If you are trying to change the entire timezone of the project you can do in settings.py by: TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/kolkata' or any timezone you want

Comment: No I want Twitter like time that's why I need to detect timezone of user. How to do that in django

Answer (score 0):

One way to this is by using the Freegeoip API. It provides us with 10,000 requests per hour by default.

Step 1: Get user timezone:

```
import requests

freegeoip_response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json')
freegeoip_response_json = freegeoip_response.json()
user_time_zone = freegeoip_response_json['time_zone']
```

Setp 2: Activate Timezone

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

....
timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(user_time_zone))
```

You can add middleware like this aswell:

```
class UserTimezoneMiddleware(object):
    """ Middleware to check user timezone. """
    def process_request(self, request):
        user_time_zone = request.session.get('user_time_zone', None)
        try:
            if user_time_zone is None:
                freegeoip_response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/{0}'.format(ip))
                freegeoip_response_json = freegeoip_response.json()
                user_time_zone = freegeoip_response_json['time_zone']
                if user_time_zone:
                    request.session['user_time_zone'] = user_time_zone
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(user_time_zone))
        except:
            pass
        return None
```

For more help: [Visit Here](https://codingpub.dev/getting-user-timezone-in-django/)